# Notification tap event without showing an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I want to assign an event that will fire when a notification is being tapped on, without showing an activity (like explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#DirectEntry)).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by registering a Broadcast Receiver. This way, you can run code in the receiver when your notification is clicked, without showing any UI whatsoever if you want.

Basic receiver code:

```
public class Provider extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        //Your code here

    }
}
```

In the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="Provider" />
```

Sample code for the notification:

```
public static void showNotification(Context context) {
    CharSequence title = "title";
    CharSequence message = "text";

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(<image>, title, System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Provider.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(<notification id>, notification);
}
```